# To run two or more .VBS script parallely

Tags: vbscript

I have two .vbs file say a.vbs and b.vbs.Now both are written for the same Excel,but would work on 2 different sheets.So can we run those in parallel?

***EDIT***

a.vbs will update sheet2 and b.vbs will update sheet3.But for both source sheet is sheet1.

Please advice how to set such environment

***CODE A***

```
Option Explicit

Dim objExcel1
Dim strPathExcel1
Dim objSheet1,objSheet2
Dim IntRow1,IntRow2
Dim ColStart

Set objExcel1 = CreateObject("Excel.Application")'Object for Condition Dump

 strPathExcel1 = "D:\AravoVB\Copy of Original     Scripts\CopyofGEWingtoWing_latest_dump_21112012.xls"
 objExcel1.Workbooks.open strPathExcel1
 Set objSheet1 = objExcel1.ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets(1)
 Set objSheet2 = objExcel1.ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Bad Data")

 objExcel1.ScreenUpdating = False
 objExcel1.Calculation = -4135  'xlCalculationManual

 IntRow2=2
 IntRow1=4
 Do Until IntRow1 > objSheet1.UsedRange.Rows.Count

  ColStart = objExcel1.Application.WorksheetFunction.Match("Parent Business Process ID", objSheet1.Rows(3), 0) + 1 

Do Until ColStart > objSheet1.UsedRange.Columns.Count And objSheet1.Cells(IntRow1,ColStart) = ""

    If objSheet1.Cells(IntRow1,ColStart + 1) > objSheet1.Cells(IntRow1,ColStart + 5) And objSheet1.Cells(IntRow1,ColStart + 5) <> "" Then
    
    objSheet1.Range(objSheet1.Cells(IntRow1,1),objSheet1.Cells(IntRow1,objSheet1.UsedRange.Columns.Count)).Copy
    objSheet2.Range(objSheet2.Cells(IntRow2,1),objSheet2.Cells(IntRow2,objSheet1.UsedRange.Columns.Count)).PasteSpecial
    IntRow2=IntRow2+1
    Exit Do
    
    End If

ColStart=ColStart+4
Loop

 IntRow1=IntRow1+1
 Loop

 objExcel1.ScreenUpdating = True
 objExcel1.Calculation = -4105   'xlCalculationAutomatic
```

***CODE B***

```
Option Explicit

Dim objExcel1
Dim strPathExcel1
Dim objSheet1,objSheet2
Dim IntRow1,IntRow2
Dim Flag
Dim IntColTemp,IntRowTemp
Dim Strcmp1,Strcmp2

 Flag=0
 IntColTemp=1
 IntRowTemp=3

   Set objExcel1 = CreateObject("Excel.Application")'Object for Condition Dump

 If Err.Number <> 0 Then
     On Error GoTo 0
     Wscript.Echo "Excel application not found."
     Wscript.Quit
 End If

 strPathExcel1 = "D:\VA\CopyofGEWingtoWing_latest_dump_21112012.xls"
  objExcel1.Workbooks.open strPathExcel1

 Set objSheet1 = objExcel1.ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets(1)
 Set objSheet2 = objExcel1.ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets(2)

 IntRow1=4
 IntRow2=1

 Do While objSheet1.Cells(IntRow1, 1).Value <> ""

  objSheet2.Cells(IntRow2, 1).Value = objSheet1.Cells(IntRow1, 1).Value
 

IntColTemp=1
Flag=0
'This will travarse to the Parent Business Process ID column horizantally in the excel.
Do While Flag=0

  If objSheet1.Cells(IntRowTemp,IntColTemp).Value="Parent Business Process ID" Then

      Flag=1       

  End If
 
      IntColTemp=IntColTemp+1
      

Loop
      IntColTemp=IntColTemp-1
      'MsgBox(IntColTemp)
  
    Strcmp1=trim(objSheet1.Cells(IntRow1, 1).Value)
    Strcmp2=trim(objSheet1.Cells(IntRow1,IntColTemp).Value)

  If Strcmp1=Strcmp2 Then

      objSheet2.Cells(IntRow2, 2).Value="Parent" 

  Else

      objSheet2.Cells(IntRow2, 2).Value="child"

  End If


   IntRow1=IntRow1+1
   IntRow2=IntRow2+1

   Loop
```

Comment: I think they would need to be called from outside of Excel, due to Excel running on VBA/VB6 which by default does not support multi-threading.  Can you give more details about what each script does to each sheet, even perhaps post the code, we may be able to offer another solution?

Comment: Sure,I will. Please see the update.

Comment: Can you Please check my update?

Comment: Ok I see both scripts run on different xls files, could you elaborate on why the scripts need to be run simultaneously please?

Comment: No Matt, By Mistake those excel sheets names are differently attached.They should be same,and in reality it is so.During testing i might changed those names,wrongly pasted here also.

Comment: But now my concern is that both the scripts are doing different jobs in the same sheet,thus I thought if i could run then parallely,it might save overall performance time.

Comment: Unfortunately VB6 doesn't natively support multi-threading so one will have to run after the other. However if there are performance problems please step through the code in break mode to identify which area's are slow and then re-post these details, perhaps we can streamline the code to improve the performance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Working on two different sheets should be possible by putting something like this in both of your scripts:

```
strPathExcel1 = "D:\CopyofGEWingtoWing_latest_dump_21112012.xls"

On Error Resume Next
Set objExcel1 = GetObject(, "Excel.Application")    ' attach to running instance
If Err.Number = 429 Then                            ' if that fails
  Err.Clear
  Set objExcel1 = CreateObject("Excel.Application") ' create new instance
  If Err Then                                       ' if that still fails
    WScript.Echo Err.Description & " (0x" & Hex(Err.Number) & ")"
    WScript.Quit 1                                  ' report error and terminate
  End If
  objExcel1.Workbooks.Open strPathExcel1
End If
On Error Goto 0
```

However, I doubt that this approach would gain you enough performance to justify the additional complexity.

In ***CODE A*** replace the lines

```
Set objExcel1 = CreateObject("Excel.Application")'Object for Condition Dump

strPathExcel1 = "D:\AravoVB\Copy of Original Scripts\CopyofGEWingtoWing_latest_dump_21112012.xls"
objExcel1.Workbooks.open strPathExcel1
```

with the above code block.

In ***CODE B*** replace the lines

```
Set objExcel1 = CreateObject("Excel.Application")'Object for Condition Dump

If Err.Number <> 0 Then
  On Error GoTo 0
  Wscript.Echo "Excel application not found."
  Wscript.Quit
End If

strPathExcel1 = "D:\VA\CopyofGEWingtoWing_latest_dump_21112012.xls"
objExcel1.Workbooks.open strPathExcel1
```

with the above code block.

Comment: "On Error Goto 0" what this statement does?  And should I put this code to top of my both codes?

Comment: `On Error Resume Next` enables error "handling" in VBScript, `On Error Goto 0` disables it (see the [documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/53f3k80h%28v=vs.84%29.aspx) for details). The code snippet from my answer is supposed to replace the line `Set objExcel1 = CreateObject("Excel.Application")` in your scripts. You need to adjust the variable names, though.

Comment: I understand what you are talking about,But wanted to know in which part of the code i have to place error handling block? In last of the code?

Comment: I updated my answer, so it should become clearer what should be replaced with what.

Comment: Thank you very much! I will Check and Let you ask if I have any doubt!

Comment: I Understood,but one confusion is both the code of mine is two different .vbs file.How both can be initiated? Say A.vbs and B.vbs two files. Now I double clicked on the A.vbs,it started and then clicked on B.vbs,it also started.Then I hope your code will help them to carry on.Now programmitacly how would I strat at the same time,without any click - this is the main concern of mine.Hope you get my point.

Comment: Create 2 scheduled tasks starting at the same time, or create a batch file launching the two VBScripts via `start /b`. Still, I strongly suspect that you're trying to solve a symptom rather than the actual problem.